Creating release branches via github workflow actions with specific files from monorepo
I am trying to basically only copy the dist and the package.json of my packages into their respected release branches that should be created. I am using act to test the action locally, and I just keep getting errors on every iteration I attempt. Always has something to do with missing files.
Some context - I need to install my packages (different monorepo) to another repo so I’m trying to create release branches so I can just point to the branch for installation
This is within the same organization
Monorepo structure
.github/workflow/release.yml
packages/
packageA
packageB
package.json
name: Build and Deploy Viewer and Viewer-React Packages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  NODE_VERSION: '18'

jobs:
  build-and-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Viewer Package
        run: |
          npm run viewer-ci

      - name: Build Viewer-React Package
        run: |
          npm run viewer-react-ci

      - name: Create and Push Release Branches
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com

          for package in viewer viewer-react; do
            version=$(jq -r .version packages/$package/package.json)
            branch="release/$package-v$version"
            temp_dir="temp/$package"

            mkdir -p "$temp_dir/dist"
            cp -v packages/$package/dist/* "$temp_dir/dist/" 2>/dev/null || :
            cp -v packages/$package/package.json "$temp_dir/"

            if [ "$package" = "viewer-react" ]; then
              viewer_version=$(jq -r .version packages/viewer/package.json)
              jq --arg viewerVersion "git+https://github.com/ORG/Viewer.git#release/viewer-v$viewer_version" \
                '.peerDependencies["viewer"] = $viewerVersion' \
                "$temp_dir/package.json" > "$temp_dir/tmp.json" && mv "$temp_dir/tmp.json" "$temp_dir/package.json"
            fi

            git checkout --orphan $branch
            git rm -rf .

            cp -rv "$temp_dir"/* .

            echo "Contents of '$branch':"
            ls -lR
          done

          rm -rf temp

I had the git push logic in here - but I think I need to step back and go simple first.
This currently does create a temp folder with the correct contents - now I just need to push only the contents of the temp folder into the branch.

I would just build the package and publish it to your github-package-registry feed. Then you should install it from there. Don't add build artifacts to source control, unless you're creating your own github action
